# How to Change the success message in the popup when click add to cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css

How to Change the success message in the popup when click add to cart?
https://ibb.co/nigBmy

Comment: @SukumarGorai can you help me in this?

Comment: As far as i know this not a default funcnality of magento. You can search that text in all your files.

Comment: You need to use Ajax add to cart. I am off today, will definitely help you tomm.

Comment: You can use this ajaxcart extension and need to change some css according to your requirement. https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-ajax-add-to-cart/

Comment: @SukumarGorai I'm using magento 1.9 ...did you checked my url? https://www.equipus.com/   , there is a pop up that already appears.

Comment: Ah sorry. Wait I am sharing another one.

Comment: great! :) :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the theme you have mentioned before. I have checked the file system you need to goto below file location:

> app/code/local/Magiccart/Magicshop/controllers/AjaxController.php

Goto function **addToCartResponse** and update the text according to your requirement.

Also if you want to change the font size of that text you need to add the below css to your css file:

```
#popupAjaxcart .product-name {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great help, but I want to minimize the extensions I have as much as possible, if you check my screen-shot, there is Ajax pop up in my website, and I'm satisfied with it, just need to know from where to edit the message inside it, have a check in my screenshot https://ibb.co/mPbojJ

Comment: I'm using alothemes/supermarket which comes with Ajax defualt popup I guess, as you see in the backend there is a menu with a name magic cart, but I can't find the code of the popup https://ibb.co/enWXBy  :ie; i'm didn't install any plugin for ajax pop up till now, it's default

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: You are Amazing @Sukumar Gorai,, Appreaciate your help mate :) :) :)